# I am creating array of sprites getting error

Tags: c++, arrays, cocos2d-x

i need help? how to remove this error please help to fix me and how add sprites in this array..As i   tired with spritesWithfile and NsmutableArray is not working in cocos2d 2.2.0.4 so please let  me know

```
cocos2d::CCArray *arr;  
cocos2d::CCSprite *foo;  
arr->addObject(foo);

CCObject *item;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(arr, item) // here i am getting error as no member 'data' is present in                   cocos2d::ccsprite
{
  // i have left blank in my code 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are trying to create an array of `CCSprite*`?

I dont have 2.0.4 documentation handy to tell you what default constructors you could take advantage of. so I'll do it a way I know will work.

```
cocos2d::CCArray* arr = new CCAray();

for (int i=0, i < 5; i++)
{
    CCSprite* foo = new cocos2d::CCSprite(); 
    foo->initWithFile( "sprite.png" );

    arr->addObject(foo);
}
```

I dont prefer `CCArray`, I just use an `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<CCSprite*> _sprites;
_sprites.reserve(<some initial amount>); // if this makes sense for you.

for (int i=0, i < 5; i++)
{
    CCSprite* foo = new cocos2d::CCSprite(); 
    foo->initWithFile( "sprite.png" );

    v.push_back(foo);
}
```

Comment: cocos2d::CCArray* arr = new CCAray();

for (int i=0, i < 5; i++)
{
    CCSprite* foo = new cocos2d::CCSprite(); 
    foo->initWithFile( "sprite.png" );

    arr->addObject(foo);
}    thanks for response  In initwithfile we can added any no of sprites?? if yes then  how to create a file of sprites i know this nt valid question but i am new to this cocos2d so please help..